# Adding a char to a string literal with C

Tags: c, char, string-literals

I have defined a string literal as

`char *name`

and I want to add a char to `name` (the char is defined as `char d = 'a'`).

I have tried

`strcpy(name, d);`

but when I try to print it I get a seg fault. How could I do this?

Comment: Define the character you want to append as a char* (or char array) instead, then use strcat: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/.

Comment: @slugonamission My application prevents the use of C++. Only C.

Comment: er...`strcat` is in the C standard library...

Comment: The use of `strcat` should be banished. At least, `strncat` should be used to avoid unsafe copies.

Comment: @Halim Qarroum `strncat` requires a third parameter `n` which is the maximum length to append, not the max size of the resultant destination.  Seen enough incorrect uses `n` with `strncat` to conclude it not any less problematic than `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `name[strlen(name)] = d`.

```
char *name = malloc(80);
// some code that puts something in *name
strcpy(name, "Hello World");
char d = 'a'
size_t len = strlen(name);
if (len >= (80-1)) DealWithNotEnoughRoom(); 
name[len++] = d;
name[len] = '\0';
```

BTW:
`char *name` is not a string literal. "Hello World" above is a string literal.
`char *name` is a variable "name as pointer to char".

Answer (score 0):

You have defined name as a pointer to a fixed location in memory (probably in the initialized data segment). You need not a pointer, but a vector with enough size to accomodate the original string and the string you want to append to.

```
char d[100];  /* enough room for a string of 99 characters */

strcpy (d, "a");  /* initialize d with string "a" */
strcat (d, "b");  /* append "b" to d, resulting in "ab" */
```

If you want to append a single character stored in a `char` variable, you may do as this:

```
char c='b';
char d[100];  /* enough room for a string of 99 characters */

strcpy (d, "a");  /* initialize d with string "a" */
d[strlen(d)+1]='\0'; /*  add the character stored in c to string d */
d[strlen(d)]=c;      /*            resulting in "ab"               */
```